# Javascript printing out attributes of a record that are kept in a record

Tags: javascript

The title might not be very clear, I'll try my best to explain it.

My array `var countryArr` is a JSON array with different attributes.

I have an array of attributes `attributeArr = ["ISO_id", "bronze"]`.

I would like to print all the record of the countryArr and all their attribute in a concise way. So I tried doing like this.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < countryArr.length; i++) { 
        for(var j in attributeArr) {
            console.log(countryArr[i].attributeArr[j]);
    }
```

Can this work? At the moment is not printing out anything.

Comment: Why don't you print directly `countryArr`? Like `console.log(countryArr)`

Comment: Add the contents of countryArr

Comment: Because this prints it out as an array. I'd like to access each individual elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that the items in `countryArr` are JSON objects, this is what you should do:

```
var countryArr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}];
var attributeArr = ['a','b'];
for(var i = 0; i < countryArr.length; i++) { 
    for(var j in attributeArr) {
        console.log(countryArr[i][attributeArr[j]]);
    }
}

// --> 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Will accept your answer in 9 minutes :)